Predicting the bottom right entry in the output QR decomposition
The following may sound like a very niche question, but a good answer would advance lattice reduction. See details below.
As an example, consider the matrix
A = \begin{bmatrix}
.111 & .025 & .010 & .007\\
0 & .110 & .028 & .037\\
0 & 0 & .109 & .060\\
0 & 0 & 0 & .108\\
\end{bmatrix}
I would like to know whether, given a matrix like A, there is a transformation A ← QAP where

Q is orthogonal
P is a matrix with integer entries and determinant 1 or -1
QAP is still upper triangular,
|(QAP)[4][4]| > |A[4][4]|

In the case of A given above, the answer is "yes". One solution, which increases A[4][4] from .108000 to .108131, is to set P to the permutation matrix that reverses the order of the four columns, and set
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0.054 &  0.286 & 0.465 & 0.836\\
0.071 &  0.115 & 0.847 & -0.514\\
0.208 &  0.925 & -0.257 & -0.188\\
0.974 & -0.221 & -0.032 & 0.031
\end{bmatrix}
In certain cases, like the one above, I can answer this question in the affirmative by cycling P through possible permutations and, for each P, choosing Q to rotate away the non-zero entries that appear below the diagonal of AP. But I would like to

Generalize beyond permutations for P and dimension 4 x 4
Use properties of A, like the norms and correlations of its columns (or eigenvalues or whatever), to predict when such a transformation is possible.

An example where A cannot be transformed -- at least not if P is a permutation -- is A as given above but replacing .010 with -.010 in A[1][3]. Notice that this reduces the correlation between column 3 and the other columns, so I think column correlations may be part of the answer.
The reason the above is more than a niche question is that a good answer would advance lattice reduction with PSLQ. It would amount to a technique for increasing |H[n-1][n-1]| as defined in that paper. According to lemma 10 in a 1999 PSLQ paper, the larger |H[n-1][n-1]| is when PSLQ is about to terminate, the shorter its solution vector will be. Current techniques rely heavily on 2 x 2 versions of the question I'm asking. In fact, the 2 x 2 case is completely solved in my work on PSLQ. There, I have also added to the mix an equivalent of non-adjacent column swaps in A using unsophisticated criteria that I'd like to improve on. Even with these unsophisticated criteria, non-adjacent column swaps do generate solutions that would otherwise not be found, but this improvement is marginal.

As far as knowing right away whether there is a solution without knowing the solution itself (assuming there is one), that might be difficult.
But there is a way to search a tree of possible solutions. In cases like the example given in the question, where it is hard to find an answer, the tree may have substantially fewer than $2^{n-1}$ nodes, where n is the dimension of A.
Let $B=A^{-1}$ and set $q=\alpha(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)B$ where $v_1=1$ and the other $v_i$ are integers. Require $|\alpha>A_{n,n}|$ and, for each i, $\sum^i_{j=1}q_j^2\leq1$. The choices of $v_i$ will be constrained by those requirements. This keeps the tree of possible answers small as you iterate through the indices i=2,...,n choosing the $v_i$.
When $i=n$, full equality is reached: $\sum^n_{j=1}q_j^2=|q|=1$. Since |q|=1, there is an orthogonal matrix $Q_1$ whose last row is q. Since $q=\alpha(1,v_2,...,v_n)B$, there is a matrix P with integer entries and determinant $\pm1$ such that the last row $(Q_1AP)_n$ of $Q_1AP$ is $(0,0,...,\alpha)$. This leaves arbitrary entries below the diagonal in the first n-1 rows of $Q_1AP$. A further left-multiplication by some orthogonal matrix $Q_2$ with (0,0,...,1) in its last row and last column (essentially, an n-1 x n-1 orthogonal matrix, extended to n dimensions) can zero out these entries. Then $Q_2Q_1AP$ is upper triangular. Since left-multiplying  by $Q_2$ leaves row n fixed, $|(Q_2Q_1AP)_{n,n}|=|(Q_1AP)_{n,n}|=\alpha$ > $|A_{n,n}|$ as desired.
The claim above that the size of the search tree for v may be far less than $2^{n-1}$ is based on a heuristic involving the real vector x that minimizes $\langle Bx,Bx\rangle$, subject to the condition that $x_1$=1. x is easily computed, and the error from rounding x off to get the integer vector, v, is
$\langle Bv,Bv\rangle - \langle Bx,Bx\rangle = 2\langle Bx,B(v-x)\rangle + \langle B(v-x),B(v-x)\rangle$
It is likely that optimal rounding of x to the integer vector, v, minimizes the right-hand side of the above equation, coordinate by coordinate; with perhaps a few exceptions where the coordinate-wise choice of $v_i$ needs to be modified because the errors from rounding up and down are unusually close.  If such an algorithm can be formalized and proven to work, the size of the search space can be expected to be well under $2^{n-1}$, as claimed.
To illustrate the computation of v using A as given above, set B to
$B = A^{-1}$ = \begin{bmatrix}
  9.0090 & -2.0475 & -0.3006 &  0.2845 \\
  0.0000 &  9.0909 & -2.3353 & -1.8171 \\
  0.0000 &  0.0000 &  9.1743 & -5.0968 \\
  0.0000 &  0.0000 &  0.0000 & 9.259\end{bmatrix}
Starting with $q_1$:
$1=|q|=\alpha(1,v_2,v_3,v_4)B\implies 1\geq|q_1|=\alpha B_{1,1}=\alpha(9.009)\implies |\alpha|\leq1/9.009 \approx 0.111$.
Since $0.111>0.108=A_{4,4}$, it is still possible to find a solution to the original problem. The tree of possible solutions at this point consists of the tuples $v_1=1$, $v_2$=any, $v_3$=any, $v_4$=any. But the next iteration limits $v_2$ to just one choice, as we'll see, and the remaining two iterations will do likewise.
Continuing with $q_2$:
$q_2=\alpha\langle(1,v_2),(-2.0475,9.0909)\rangle$
If $v_2\neq0$,
$q_2^2\geq\alpha^2(-2.0475+9.0909)^2=\alpha^2(7.0434^2)$
$\implies 1=|q|\geq\sqrt{q_1^2+q_2^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2(9.009^2+7.0434^2)}\approx|\alpha|(11.4355)$
$\implies |\alpha| \leq 0.088 < 0.108 = |A_{4,4}|$
This means that $v_2$ must be 0, and $q_2=\alpha(-2.0475)$.
Continuing with $q_3$:
$q_3=\alpha\langle(1,0,v_3),(-.3006,-2.3353,9.1743)\rangle =\alpha(-.3006+v_3(9.1743))$
If $v_3\neq0$,
$q_3^2\geq\alpha^2(−.3006+9.1743)^2=\alpha^2(8.8737^2)$
$\implies 1=|q|\geq\sqrt{q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2(9.009^2+(-2.0475)^2+8.8737^2)}\approx|\alpha|(12.81)$
$\implies |\alpha| \leq 0.079 < 0.108 = |A_{4,4}|$
This means that $v_3$ must be $0$ and $q_3=\alpha(-.3006)$
Continuing with $q_4$:
$q_4=\alpha\langle(1,0,0,v_4),(0.2845,−1.8171,−5.0968,9.259)\rangle =\alpha(.2845+v_4(9.259))$
If $v_4\neq0$,
$q_3^2\geq\alpha^2(.2845-9.259)^2=\alpha^2(8.9745^2)$
$\implies 1=|q|\geq\sqrt{q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2+q_4^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2(9.009^2+(-2.0475)^2+(-.3006)^2+8.9745^2)}\approx|\alpha|(12.88)$
$\implies |\alpha| \leq 0.0777 < 0.108 = |A_{4,4}|$
This means that $v_4=0$ and $q_4=\alpha(0.2845)$.
Thus $q=\alpha(9.0090,-2.0475,-0.3006,0.2845)$
$\implies \alpha=1/\sqrt{9.0090^2+2.0475^2+0.3006^2+0.2845^2}=1/\sqrt{85.5256379}\approx 0.1081$.
$q$ can be extended to an orthogonal matrix
$Q_1$ = \begin{bmatrix}
  any \\
  any \\
  any \\
  9.0090\alpha & -2.0475\alpha & -0.3006\alpha & 0.2845\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$(Q_1A)_4=(\alpha(1,0,0,0)B)A=\alpha(1,0,0,0)(BA)=(\alpha,0,0,0)=(\approx0.1081,0,0,0)$
Right-multiplying by the permutation matrix, P, that swaps columns 1 and 4, puts the row $(0,0,0,\approx0.1081)$ in $(Q_1AP)_4$. Next, left-multiplying by some orthogonal $Q_2$ with $(0,0,0,1)$ in its last row and last column yields an upper triangular matrix $Q_2Q_1AP$ with $0.1081 \approx |(Q_2Q_1AP)_{4,4}| > |A_{4,4}| = 0.108$.

Abstract
A variant of the PSLQ algorithm is proposed that solves the smallest vector problem using a tree search, if one piece of additional information is given: the norm of the smallest solution vector. In addition, a similar algorithm is suggested that, heuristically, shows promise to solve the shortest vector problem in what appears to be polynomial time with a radically trimmed tree search. Both the polynomial time complexity and the expected success of the trimmed search are based on heuristic arguments.
Introduction
There is a way to use PSLQ to solve the smallest vector problem, given only the Euclidean norm $|m|$ of that vector. In this paper, we define this algorithm. It requires a tree search but a trimming of this tree is a fast alternative.
In [1], a matrix $H$ internal to the PSLQ algorithm is defined, and from lemma 10 one can conclude that: To solve the smallest vector problem, it suffices to make the bottom right diagonal element of $H$ equal to $1/|m|$. Here $m$ itself is not known, but $|m|$ is. Or you could just guess $|m|$ with only a linear multiple of the work, since $|m|$ is the Euclidean norm of an integer-valued vector, which must be the square root of an integer.
The classic form of PSLQ from [1] defines a sequence of iterations using particular family of row operations on $H$ that terminates in a polynomial amount of time. The row operations comprise what can be called a strategy. This paper suggests a new strategy. The replacement of the classic strategy with this one sacrifices the proof of polynomial completion time in exchange for an optimal output.
First Put Zeroes in the Bottom Row of H
In practice, it has been shown that given integer inputs $x$ = $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_n)$, iterations of the PSLQ algorithm using

swaps of adjacent pairs of diagonal elements in $H$ that increase the bottom diagonal element in the pair, and
swaps of row $n$ = $(H_{n,0} \ne 0, H_{n,1} \ne 0, ..., H_{n,j} \ne 0, 0, ..., 0)$ with row $i$

eventually lead to $H$ having zeroes in its bottom row. (It would be strange if this were not the case, because it would mean that for some $i$ with $H_{n,i} \ne 0$, $H_{i,i}/H_{n,i}$
is irrational, even though the inputs to PSLQ are all integers).
Zero or more further iterations using swaps of adjacent pairs lead to a local maximum, where no swap of adjacent pairs increases the bottom diagonal element of that pair.
Then Invert H
In high dimensions, reaching the local maximum where adjacent $H$ has zeroes in row and adjacent row swaps are exhausted does not make $|H_{n-1,n-1}|$ the largest absolute value of a diagonal element of $H$. But introducing non-adjacent row operations does make $|H_{n-1,n-1}|$ the largest absolute value of a diagonal element of $H$.
This solves the smallest vector problem, which sounds at first as if the smallest vector problem takes less than exponential time even though it's in NP. But there is a catch: you have to figure out what row operations put the maximum absolute value diagonal element in $H_{n-1,n-1}$. Theoretically, this is an exponential time tree search as we'll see. But practically, it doesn't look like a very difficult search, as we'll also see.
Once $H$ has zeroes in row $n$ -- with or without reaching a local maximum -- it is possible to turn to iterations that do not involve 2x2 matrices. Each iteration of PSLQ does these steps:

Definition of the next row operation, $R$ with integer coefficients (what were initially adjacent row swaps and swaps with row $n$); followed by $H$ $\leftarrow$ $RH$
Corner removal: $H$ $\leftarrow$ $HG$, where $G$ is an orthogonal matrix and $HG$ has only zeroes above the diagonal.
Reduction: $H$ $\leftarrow$ $DH$. $D$ is a matrix that reduces the absolute value of every element below the diagonal to at most half that of the diagonal element above it.

To find a sequence of row operations that make $|H_{n-1,n-1}|$ the largest absolute value of a diagonal element, it suffices to invert $H$ and perform column operations that maximize $(H^{-1})_{n-1,n-1}$. Minimizing the bottom right entry of $H^{-1}$ is the same as maximizing the bottom right entry of $H$ because $H_{i,i}$ = $1/(H^{-1})_{i,i}$. Note that

It makes sense to talk about the inverse of $H$ once its bottom row is all zero, because that row can be ignored, making $H$ a square matrix of dimension $n-1$.
The formula $H_{i,i}$ = $1/(H^{-1})_{i,i}$ works because $H$ is lower triangular.

Then Continue Iterating on the Inverse
Once $H$ has been inverted, one iteration of PSLQ can be defined in terms of $M$ = $H^{-1}$, keeping in mind the formula $(AB)^{-1}$ = $B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Definition of the next column operation, $S$ with integer coefficients; followed by $M$ $\leftarrow$ $MS$
Corner removal: $M$ $\leftarrow$ $GM$, where $G$ is an orthogonal matrix and $GM$ has only zeroes above the diagonal.
Reduction: $M$ $\leftarrow$ $ME$. $E$ is a matrix that reduces the absolute value of every element to the left of the diagonal to at most half that of the diagonal element to its right.

Lemma 10 in [1] says that $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$ = $1/|H_{n-1,n-1}|$ is the norm of the solution PSLQ would output in its current state. If that norm is the (known) $|m|$, terminate after step 3.
If PSLQ did not terminate after step 3, there must be a column operation to define in the next iteration that makes $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$ = $|m|$. (This last assertion is a bit out of scope for this article; it follows from the fact that $m$ is the rightmost column of some invertible matrix with integer entries, and that PSLQ can generate all such matrices).
The full search for $S$ consists of checking whether any of columns $n-2$, ..., $0$ has norm less than $|M_{n-1,n-1}$; then trying pairs of columns with integer coefficients $(1,1),(1,-1),(1,2),...$. Not every possible pair of weights needs to be tried, since at some point it will be clear that the norm of the combination will be less than $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$. After trying 2 at time, combinations of 3 at a time can be tried, etc.
This full search, which can be viewed as a tree search, is guaranteed to solve the smallest vector problem. However, the full search is of course impractical. The reason it is of interest is that only very small combinations of columns of $M$ are likely to have norm less than $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$.
In fact, by far the most likely column combinations to have norm less than $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$ are those that involve just one column, because any time two or more columns are combined, a comparatively large diagonal entry is added to an interior row of a column to its left. This addition to the norm of the column combination must be offset by cancellations in the other rows. The more columns are involved, and the higher their coefficients,
Below is one sensible reduction of the full search. Until now, the arguments about the norm of $|H_{n-1,n-1}|$ that can be achieved have been precise. From here on, the arguments about this are heuristic.

Rather than trying to find the minimum-norm combination of columns at each iteration, settle for one that reduces $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$. Since $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$ is the norm of a solution to $\langle,x,m\rangle$ = $0$, the possible values of $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$ form a discrete, finite subset of the square roots of integers, so this search terminates in a linear number of reductions, as a function of the initial $|M_{n-1,n-1}|$.
Consider only one column at a time
But to expand the search, allow replacement of columns $n-2$, $n-3$, ... in that order of precedence.
When all columns of $M$ are sorted with high norm columns on the left and low norm columns on the right, terminate PSLQ.

The only condition that would thwart the above trimmed search is the existence of a combination of two or more columns in $M$ with a lower norm than any one column of $M$. While this condition is likely to emerge for a high enough dimension, $n$, the trimmed search is expected to succeed for moderate dimensions, e.g. $n < 100$. As the dimension is increased, the trimming can be loosened by considering pairs of columns, then three columns at a time, etc.
References
[1] Helaman Ferguson, David H. Bailey and Steve Arno - Analysis of PSLQ, an Integer Relation Finding Algorithm https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00995-3/S0025-5718-99-00995-3.pdf
